# Polymer: How to implement navigations

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

The way I currently implemented navigation in my Polymer 1 application is this:

- I use `paper-menu` and `paper-submenu`
- on `iron-select`, I will create a route based on the names of the `paper-item`

for example `groups`, `example`, `test` will be concatinated into a route like: `/groups/example/test`. User when then be routed there using `this.set('route.path', '/groups/example/test')`

Also, on page load, to highlight the correct menu items, I parse the URL and selected the correct menu items. So far so good.

The problem here is: suppose I have even further nesting like `/groups/example/test/subpage1/subsubpage2`. When the user navigates to such a URL, he is forced back to `/groups/example/test` because the parsing of URL to select the correct items.

The workaround I have currently is: instead of attaching `on-iron-select` I will `setTimeout` then attach this handler. This is so that the user does not get forced back to the wrong page, but this feels wrong. Whats the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Take a look at app-route; this seems to be the polymer-recommended approach to routing. Use this in combination with iron-pages or neon-animated-pages to handle transitioning your views! https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/toolbox/routing

Comment: @CalvinBelden, so using nested routers for each nested route? That works fine just that theres alot of boilerplate code for each router

Comment: Ya, so you would end up having an app-route instance at each level of your hierarchy. Of course, you don't **need** to implement your routing this way. For example, I've used page.js (with iron-pages) to manage routing in a Polymer app, and that worked just fine. https://visionmedia.github.io/page.js/